# Restrict Exchange Outbound Bandwidth

Tags: exchange-2007

Scenario: An employee sent a mass email to our customers with a large (7mb) PDF attachment. This crippled out internet connection.

System:
Exchange 2007
Cable Internet Connection (7Mbit/s down x 1Mbit/s up)

**Is there any way to throttle our outbound exchange bandwidth?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more concerned about fixing the human behaviour that thought this was a good idea tbh.

Not sure of any way within Exchange, you can set things like SMTP concurrent connections but AFAIK it'll take as much bandwidth as it can.

Probably something best done on your firewall.

Comment: +1 for doing it on the firewall, and also @Carl - beat the user with a large stick and tell them not to do it again!

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the bandwidth (on the Exchange server) but you can control the maximum message size that's allowed to be sent through the Send Connector. If you don't want to limit the message size globally you could create a Transport Rule that restricts this user from sending messages that exceed a certain size.